# OpenShift File-Upload directory none function

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

this site : [Link-To-Site](http://www.webwedding.co.il) , is now fully working, I have uploaded the project a nodejs project from my local computer, it worked great on local pc.

Now I'm using OpenShift to host the site, again all seems to work great but this directory in the project "fileupload" I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`  on that page,I have added a screeshot of `rhc tail -a appname`.

Note that I have heared about $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, I dont see how it has to do with this,or how to make it work, thanks ahead.

Edit- Adding Node.js Code, might be usful.

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(req.files.files[0].path, function (err, data) {
        var imageName = req.files.files[0].name
        /// If there's an error
        if(!imageName){
            console.log("There was an error")
            res.redirect("/");
            res.end();
        } else {
            var img_path = req.files.files[0].path;
           var file_read  = fs.readFile(img_path, function(err, data){
               var BucketName = 'webwedding/'+SSName;
               s3.createBucket({Bucket: BucketName}, function() {
                   var params = {Bucket: BucketName,ACL: "public-read" , Key: imageName, Body: data};
                   s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                   //  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                       if (err) {
                           console.log(err)
                           res.end(err);
                       }
                       else      {
                           console.log('Uploaded ' + imageName +' To '+SSName);
                           var files = req.files.files[0];
                         //  console.log(files);
                           res.json(200, { files: JSON.stringify(files) });
                       }
                   });
               });
           });
        }
    });
});
```

[Dropbox-ScreenShot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6b8gqif40tsjqhh/upload.png)

Comment: The function os.tmpDir() in multiparty failed. I tried on my openshift it work. is your tmp env variable not set?

Comment: "is your tmp env variable not set?" if you can explain it better, new to OpenShift issues.
I guess it's not set.

Comment: What version of node cartridge did you installed? if you install 0.6x then os.tmpDir() is not available. that will pretty much give you the error in your screen shot. 0.8x or 0.10 will be fine.

Comment: Node Version is 0.10.15, so it doens't seems to be the problem

Comment: you can Option1: putty into server start node cli checking os.tmpDir() exists or not. Option2: use [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) for file uploading rather than bodyparser, bodyparser is obsolete and not recommended to use, make sure set the uploadDir. Option3: change your code to do client side upload to S3 directly without proxy the upload.

Comment: I dont know really how to excute the options really, but I think I will try to do Option2, altrough it will make me use a lot of changes, about Option1 how do I check if os.tmpDir() exists?

Comment: I putty into the server. then I type node and press enter. put `var os = require('os'); console.log(os.tmpDir());`

Comment: I get TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tmpDir', that is the problem.. I think, but it's node ver 0.10.15 so how can it be explained?